# merged robots output.xmls file do not have timestamps

Tags: merge, robotframework

I have run robot suite with 3 tests, 2/3 was passed. After that I run same pybot command with option --rerun first_run_output.xml, 1 test was passed. Next I run rebot -o merged.xml --merge first_run_output.xml rerun_output.xml

In merged.xml the test witch was failed and rerun in merged.xml has starttime="N/A" and endtime="N/A", this value propagate up in xml (parents nodes has also "N/A" value in timestamps)

```
Reassuming:
- run pybot - A-pass B-pass C-failed -> generate first_run_output.xml
- run pybot --rerun - C-passed -> generate rerun_output.xml
- run rebot -o merged.xml --merge first_run_output.xml rerun_output.xml
- In first_run_output.xml and rerun_output.xml ale starttime and endtime has data value
- In merged.xml in Node <status> for C has  starttime="N/A" endtime="N/A" and parents of suite C (thats aggregate A,B,C) also have starttime="N/A" endtime="N/A"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ask same question on robotframe-user group,
answer is "This is by design"
details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/TWvZMtbizrs